# Tableview custom cell doesnt connect button to its action

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I made a custom cell, and it has `UIButton` in it.
For some reason, some of these cells connected the button to its action, and some didn't, so all of these cells have the button, but some of them don't do anything when clicking.

Maybe someone can help me with that?

Thank you.

Comment: post code of custom cell.

Comment: If your cell is in a Storyboard you have to connect it each time to the ViewController it's supposed to be in everytime. Storyboards for UITableViewCell's are fine for cells that only exist in one view controller. I would programmatically create the cell if you plan on using it in multiple view controllers

Comment: Please provide some screenshot or a bit of code. Or try to use 'func didSelectRowAt:...' for event of tapping a row especially when displaying multiple rows with selecting actions. iOS design is standing primarily on this ability when using UITableView.

Comment: without any code you cannot be helped out! Or at least an image...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i tracked the problem, it doesnt works for the cells that wont be seen at the begining but you can see them after scrolling i have 2 tableviews that need to be lined up all the time so i use scroll view and think thats where the problem comes from, so i just deleted the scroll view and it is now working